# Looking for a solution to setup web video streaming from hdd ( local network only )

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a simple solution to have a website for streaming my video files ( embedded video ) from HDD. I plan to use this in the local network only so transcoding is not needed. I currently have a samba server running but I need a seeking feature that doesn't require to download the whole file. Playlist support would be great.

Comment: What devices? Would a mini-DLNA setup work?

Comment: I have minidlna running, the problem is finding dlna renderers for various platforms. A website is pretty bog standard and would definitly make it simple. Mainly desktop devices are inteded for this use.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://clipbucket.com/).

But this is not *as* simple. You need to setup a webserver with php support (which is basically installing apache and php from the package manager of your distro) and to follow the instructions for clipbucket...

Comment: Thanks but I settled on using plex it offers most of what I wanted.